# Netdata Tor plugin configuration

Tags: monitoring, tor, netdata

Netdata mentions how to set up their tor plugin to be able to monitor traffic: https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/collectors/python.d.plugin/tor

However they do not detail how do you specify the password

How do you configure your control port for Netdata Tor plugin?

This is not enough:

```
local_tcp:
 name: 'local'
 control_port: 9051
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i just guessed the config field name for password was:

```
local_tcp:
 name: 'local'
 control_port: 9051
 password: yourtorconfigportpassword
```

I'm Sherlock!

Comment: Thanks detective!  :) 

I just made a PR to be clearer on this: https://github.com/netdata/netdata/pull/13966. This is where the code looks for the `password` param: https://github.com/netdata/netdata/blob/44a75ea996268466c38b596294677f3b80350103/collectors/python.d.plugin/tor/tor.chart.py#L44